# How to pass JRBeanCollectionDataSource to List component in iReport Designer?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have a bar chart in title band of my report which is filled by a list of objects from my *Java* application. (*category expression = $F{ip} and value expression = $F{occurrence}*)

I want to put a list component beside a bar chart in *Title* band of my report. I couldn't find how I can configure a *List* component.

I have set Connection/Datasource Expression of a list component to Use connection expression. I have defined two fields *ip* and o*ccurrence*, and put *`$F{ip}`* and *1$F{occurrence}`* inside the list, but it doesn't work.

It would be great if anyone can help me to pass a same list which I have used to fill the bar chart to the list component.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Datsource expression instead for your list and pass your bean collection datasource.
That should work.